# Generate random value once for every issue Python

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate random title for an auction and then use it outside the method.

add_consignment.py:

```
class AddConsignmentPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super(AddConsignmentPage, self).__init__(driver, self._title)
        self._title_uuid = get_random_uuid(7)

inst = AddConsignmentPage(AddConsignmentPage)
```

and I want to use the same _title_uuid to view added consignment (type its title into search field)

view_consignments.py

```
from pages.add_consignment import inst
class ViewConsignmentsPage(BasePage):
    _title_uuid = inst._title_uuid

    def check_added_consignment(self):
        self.send_keys(self._title_uuid, self._auction_search)
```

In this scenario the title is generated two times so title in added consignment is different than title in search field

So how to pass the value of _title_uuid from AddConsignmentPage to ViewConsignmentsPage? I want it to be the same in two methods, but different for every consignment(test case)

How to get it generated once for every consignment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by adding ViewConsignmentsPage._title_uuid = self._title_uuid to init method

add_consignment.py:

```
from pages.view_consignments import ViewConsignmentsPage

class AddConsignmentPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super(AddConsignmentPage, self).__init__(driver, self._title)
        self._title_uuid = get_random_uuid(7)
        ViewConsignmentsPage._title_uuid = self._title_uuid
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `_title_uuid` is a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) and not an instance variable: It's only initialized once. But if you initialize it in the constructor, it should work.

See also [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

E.g.,

```
import random

class Foo:
    num1 = random.randint(1,10)

    def __init__(self):
        self.num2 = random.randint(1,10)

for n in range(10):
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.num1, foo.num2)
```

Running the above gives:

```
(7, 2)
(7, 6)
(7, 6)
(7, 5)
(7, 7)
(7, 1)
(7, 2)
(7, 3)
(7, 7)
(7, 7)
```

You can also do `print(Foo.num1)` here, if that clarifies anything, but not `print(Foo.num2)` because that only exists for instantiated objects.

As you can see, `num1` is initialized once, while `num2` is initialized for every instantiation of the object.

In you case, you can probably just do:

```
class AddConsignmentPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AddConsignmentPage, self).__init__() # initializes BasePage
        self._title_uuid = get_random_uuid(7)

    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the _title_uuid inside an `__init__` method since the value on the class will be changed each time.

In your case it could be:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
   super(AddConsignmentPage, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
   self._title_uuid = get_random_uuid(7)
```